# Changing the border color of a submit button after clicking it, CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a submit button with the background color of green. When clicking on it, it changes the background color to red, but after clicking it, the background color changes back to green, and there is a blue border surrounding the button. I'm wondering if there is a way to get rid of the blue borders? Thank you.

```
input[type=submit] {
background-color: green;
}
input[type=submit]:active {
background-color: red;
}

<input type = 'submit' value = 'Click me'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `outline` to `0` and add `:focus` to the button, which means after it has been clicked and remains in focus.

```
input[type=submit]:focus {
  background-color: green;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Want do you want to do with the button, should he be green or red after click? Remove the border( if the elem has one ) and the outline....should do the trick.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

```
input[type=submit]:active{
      background-color: green;
      outline: 0;
      border: none;
    }
```

Comment: It should be :focus not :active as active only reacts to when the user is clicking, not when the element is in focus.

Comment: :focus it is, i misunderstood the question. Thanks